# How to draw shapes interactively on top of a HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, shapes, mouse-cursor

I need to draw a shape on top of a HTML5 canvas with the mouse cursor, like a square or a circle; and it should be resizable, then, when the user has finished with the drawing, the coordinates of the shape inside the canvas should be retrievable.

Any ideas of how can I achieve this using JavaScript?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Canvas knows definitely nothing about the nature of objects you are drawing. That means than after calling, say, `arc` method, all you get is just a bunch of pixels on the screen.

There are two approaches here - you can write you own object model wrapper above canvas. 
Each time you will be drawing something, you should store object information - shape, coordinates and anything else needed. This is quite decent approach, but be warned - it's not that trivial as one can think.

The second approach is to use SVG instead of canvas and have an object model from the box.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript library [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) might be of interest to you. to paraphrase the website intro - "This provides a vector graphics framework using the HTML 5 Canvas"